# Is there a closed form expression for the following exponential sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, roots-of-unity, exponential-sum

As part of a task given to me, I need to find a value/expression for the below sum:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{2N} e^{\frac{i \pi a^2}{2N}}$$

I've tried plugging it into python but isn't the nicest thing and I've also tried it in Wolfram but it will only tell me that it converges as $N\to \infty$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $N$ different from $n$?

Comment: Sorry, they should be the same, just changed it now.

Comment: @DanielT-K This is no a Discrete Fourier Transform?

Comment: See [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Generalized_quadratic_Gauss_sums).

Comment: *note :* $e^{\pi i}=-1$